# How to get data from this API

Tags: php

I want get data from API but I have problem:

```
foreach ($userdata as $Summoner)
{


    $response = Unirest::get("https://community-league-of-legends.p.mashape.com/api/v1.0/$region/summoner/retrieveInProgressSpectatorGameInfo/" .
        $Summoner['NICK'], array("X-Mashape-Authorization" =>
            "$key"), null);
    $array = ($response->raw_body);
    $new = json_decode($array, true);
}
```

var_dump ($new);

```
array(5) { ["playerCredentials"]=> array(11) { ["observerEncryptionKey"]=> string(32) "nZvmi1uhrXGW4hn1bD9u9eadte7x9dGK" ["dataVersion"]=> int(0) ["playerId"]=> int(28980822) ["serverPort"]=> int(0) ["observer"]=> bool(true) ["summonerId"]=> int(0) ["championId"]=> int(0) ["observerServerIp"]=> string(12) "95.172.65.26" ["gameId"]=> int(859406155) ["observerServerPort"]=> int(8088) ["lastSelectedSkinIndex"]=> int(0) } ["dataVersion"]=> int(0) ["gameName"]=> string(15) "match-859406155" ["reconnectDelay"]=> int(0) ["game"]=> array(33) { ["practiceGameRewardsDisabledReasons"]=> array(1) { ["array"]=> array(0) { } } ["glmSecurePort"]=> int(0) ["queuePosition"]=> int(0) ["playerChampionSelections"]=> array(1) { ["array"]=> array(10) .............
```

But when I loop $new

```
foreach ($new as $usrGmID) { 

}
```

I get this:
var_dump ($usrGmID);

```
array(33) { ["practiceGameRewardsDisabledReasons"]=> array(1) { ["array"]=> array(0) { } } ["glmSecurePort"]=> int(0) ["queuePosition"]=> int(0) ["playerChampionSelections"]=> array(1) { ["array"]=> array(10) { [0]=> array(6) { ["spell1Id"]=> int(14) ["spell2Id"]=> int(4) ["championId"]=> int(238) ["summonerInternalName"]=> string(4) "nali" ["selectedSkinIndex"]=> int(0) ["dataVersion"]=> int(0) } [1]=> array(6) { ["spell1Id"]=> int(4) ["spell2Id"]=> int(3) ["championId"]=> int(99) ["summonerInternalName"]=> string(9) "gamepl121"..........
```

All data that I wont to get disappears.

So my question is how i can get ["playerId"] and ["gameId"] and push this in to new array?

I try i this way:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($userdata as $Summoner)
{


    $response = Unirest::get("https://community-league-of-legends.p.mashape.com/api/v1.0/$region/summoner/retrieveInProgressSpectatorGameInfo/" .
        $Summoner['NICK'], array("X-Mashape-Authorization" =>
            "$key"), null);
    $array = ($response->raw_body);
    $new[$i] = json_decode($array, true);
    $i = $i + 1;
}

foreach ($new as $usrGmID)
{

array_push($sumgameid, array("playerId" => $usrGmID["playerCredentials"]["playerId"],
        "gameId" => $usrGmID["playerCredentials"]["gameId"]));

}
```

but this ruined all my code lines below.

Is there any other way ?

Comment: you probably don't want to share certain values (`observerEncryptionKey`) of your arrays...

Comment: This is not my key and its only example :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your accessing the array incorrectly.

Try:

```
 $new = array(
                0 => array(
                    'playerCredentials' => array(
                        'observerEncryptionKey' => '',
                        'dataVersion' => '',
                        'playerId' => 'qwe',
                        'serverPort' => '',
                        'observer' => '',
                        'gameId' => '3425'
                    )
                )
            );

        $newArray = array();

        foreach ($new as $userGmID)
        {
            $newArray[] = array('
                playerId' => $userGmID['playerCredentials']['playerId'],
                'gameId' => $userGmID['playerCredentials']['gameId']
            );
        }

        echo '<pre>', print_r($newArray, true), '</pre>';

this outputs the values of the 2 keys you are looking for. Since you have a root array that have 0 based indices, this will look and access the child keys with your data.
```

update:

in your original foreach where you do the json call

```
foreach ($userdata as $Summoner)
            {
                $response = Unirest::get("https://community-league-of-legends.p.mashape.com/api/v1.0/$region/summoner/retrieveInProgressSpectatorGameInfo/" .
                    $Summoner['NICK'], array("X-Mashape-Authorization" =>
                        "$key"), null);
                $array = ($response->raw_body);
                $new[] = json_decode($array, true);
            }
```

by using [] you are "pushing" a new array index into the array already. No need to specify the index value. I think maybe your array was being build with funky array indices.

also to avoid the error you where seeing do this

```
foreach ($new as $userGmID)
            {
                if (isset($userGmID['playerCredentials']))
                {
                    $newArray[] = array('
                    playerId' => $userGmID['playerCredentials']['playerId'],
                        'gameId' => $userGmID['playerCredentials']['gameId']
                    );
                }
            }
```

Comment: hmmm, looks like your array your feeding into the foreach isn't being populated past 0 index.